# which is the best test automation framework for automating AngularJs Single Page application?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, cucumber

i need to automate the angularjs single page application, so which stack of framework i should go with? is it Protractor + Jasmine + cucumber +selenium Framework or Ngwebdriver for selenium. Please suggest. ngwebdriver or protractor?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Protractor is an end-to-end test framework for Angular and AngularJS applications. Protractor runs tests against your application running in a real browser, interacting with it as a user would.

Refer https://www.protractortest.org/#/frameworks for choosing your framework.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Again protractor is in Javascript language and that needs to be learnt and  typescript is required for advance scripting,  i'm trying to find the  best options available with Java language. so if you know any! please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf) with Java or [BDD](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-syntax.html). You can integrate [ngWebDriver](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/qaf-users/LryqJ2qEI-8/vI5yUslzBQAJ) with QAF. It can be used for web, mobile and webservices.